# Load mappings on demand

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I have been working with vim and nvim for the last three month and I have build a good amount of mappings, after profiling my startup time I have realised the creation of all this mappings has slow down, ~40ms, my startuptime. 
I would like to know if there is a way to load mappings on demand, sort of `{ 'on': 'Mappings' }` with vim-plug, or using an if statement and load them after `vinEnter`?

Answer (score 1):

You might find what you seek in `:help autocmd` or `:help augroup`

as sergioaraujoh pointed out in his [comment]: [Load mappings on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089843/load-mappings-on-demand/63091775?noredirect=1#comment111580415_63091775)  any time you create a autocmd you should consider wrapping it with an augroup to be able to prevent multiple execution in case of douplicate autocmds.

For example, you could create a function

```
function SetMappings()
nnoremap <key-binding> <command>
... more mappings
endfunction
```

and then you would setup an autocmd to load those mappings when needed.

```
autocmd FileType php call SetMappings()
```

In this case the mappings would be set on opening a PHP file. The autocmd does not have to rely on a FileType though, `:help autocmd` really is your friend here since you are basically only limited by your imagination.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try these method as soon as I get to my computer. Do you think it would be wise to call the function on `FileType *` ?

Comment: I would recommend adding every auto command inside an  "augroup" to avoid  creating  duplicated autocommands as we see on the book "[Learning Vim The Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html)"

Comment: If all mappings are loaded on any FileType I don't think you will see the improvement in performance you were looking for in the first place. I suggest you have a look at the triggers and then start to categorize your mappings.